# Using every subqueries on where clause to count in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause

I have table `TableLL` which stores longitude and latitude, first 10 row as shown below:

```
Latitude    Longitude   ID
---------------------------
52.239215   -0.927128   1
52.627201   -1.701828   2
53.413624   -2.151294   3
52.402537   -1.519893   4
52.991135   -2.411111   5
53.409981   -2.598566   6
52.596913   -2.090278   7
52.041275   -0.777819   8
53.196655   -2.909875   9
52.945638   -1.13321    10
```

and I can count rows in different table (`MainTable`) for one latitude and one longitude from `tableLL` by using this query :

```
SELECT 
    Month, Crime_type, count(*) as TOTAL
FROM 
    MainTable
WHERE 
    ABS(MainTableLongitude - (SELECT Longitude
                              FROM TableLL
                              WHERE ID = 1)) < 0.014347 
    AND ABS(MainTableLongitude - (SELECT Latitude 
                                  FROM TableLL
                                  WHERE ID = 1)) < 0.023033
GROUP BY 
    Crime_type,MONTH
```

and result is:

```
Month      Crime_type   TOTAL
-----------------------------
2015-04     ASB         326
2015-04     Burglary     44
2015-04     CDA          50
2015-05     ASB         126
2015-05     Burglary     21
2015-05     CDA           3
2015-06     ASB          14
2015-06     Burglary      7
2015-06     CDA          58
```

But I want to count results by using all latitude and longitude in `TableLL` (I have to compare every row from `TableLL` with `MainTable`'s values in the `WHERE` clause).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In @Serif answer try to user `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE`

```
SELECT Month, Crime_type, COUNT(*) as TOTAL
FROM MainTable m
INNER JOIN TableLL t
   on ABS(m.MainTableLongitude - t.Longitude) < 0.014347 
  and ABS(m.MainTableLongitude - t.Latitude) < 0.023033
GROUP BY Crime_type,MONTH
```

Also you should consider use [spatial query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx) from sql server instead. You could create spaital index to improve overal perfomance.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT Month,Crime_type,count(*) as TOTAL
FROM MainTable, TableLL
WHERE ABS(MainTableLongitude - Longitude) < 0.014347 
AND   ABS(MainTableLongitude - Latitude)< 0.023033
GROUP BY Crime_type,MONTH
```

For to be more meaningfull you need to add some columns from TableLL to the select and group by parts.

Comment: No. TableLL stores my inputs(Latitude and Longitude).I need to use those inputs on MainTable to count crime results. I can execute my query I have no problem of doing that. but the problem is I can only execute this query by using inputs on ID=1. I wanna execute for all inputs(ID : 1 to 81(last one)) and see sum of results.

Comment: @İbrahimDilaver so you want result for each TableLL input? because this query already give you all crimes in any of those LL.

Comment: Then you dont need to add columns. That is what you are looking for.

Comment: But what causes a doubt on me is that. You are comparing ranges. So if a crime satisfies two input at the same time than it is counted twice. But if 0.014347, 0.023033 enough to distinguish inputs no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Your are right. Your way is more sensible. Skip previous answer.

```
SELECT 
    Month, Crime_type, count(*) as TOTAL
FROM 
    MainTable
WHERE 
    EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM TableLL 
            WHERE ABS(MainTableLongitude - Longitude) < 0.014347 
            AND   ABS(MainTableLongitude - Latitude ) < 0.023033
           )
GROUP BY Crime_type,MONTH
```